# cakephp label in checkbox

Tags: checkbox, label, cakephp-1.3, formhelper

i'm trying to get a checkbox with his label

```
echo $this->Form->checkbox('straordinari', array('div'=>'true', 'label' => 'Straordinari'));
```

in browser i get

```
<input id="ReportStraordinari_" type="hidden" value="0" name="data[Report][straordinari]">
<input id="ReportStraordinari" type="checkbox" value="1" label="Straordinari" div="true" name="data[Report][straordinari]">
```

but there is no label

where is the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should get what you are looking for with the following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('straordinari', array('type' => 'checkbox'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I using :

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('coupDeCoeur', 
array('div' => false,
'label' => false,
'type' => 'checkbox',
'before' => '<label class="checkbox">',
'after' => '<i></i>coupDeCoeur</label>'
));
?>
```